# How to debug an Django application running in AWS EC2

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I deployed a django app on AWS Elastic Beanstalk and did run it.
Some endpoints works well but something said `<h1>Server Error (500)</h1>`

The endpoints with taking errors works well in my local env but took above error when I run it on AWS.
So I gonna debug why it takes error...
Please help me!
Noticed: I have the ssh access. And I checked the `/var/log/` directory but I did not find the logging error of application.

Comment: be sure to have `DEBUG=True` in settings.py, could give you some hint about the error.

Comment: If you SSH, can you curl localhost to check if your application is working?

Comment: I believe DEBUG=True, when I tried to run an endpoint, it said error, other ones worked well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Find Elastic Beanstalk logs in sidebar:
   [image: elastic beanstalk logs]
2. Download full logs:
   [image: full logs]
3. Start with eb-engine.log
   [image: eb-engine]
4. Look for `[ERROR]` lines in the "tail" of that file (near the bottom). It will be obvious based on the phrase "**Executing cleanup logic**"

```
    2021/07/18 23:56:16.414159 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of ...
    
    2021/07/18 23:56:16.414169 [INFO] Executing cleanup logic
    2021/07/18 23:56:16.414270 [INFO] CommandService Response: ...
```

This will tell you the reason for the error, or it will tell you to look in one of the other files for more info.

It's pretty annoying to have to download the logs to debug. To save time, just know that you don't need to *unzip* the download after you have downloaded it; just double-click the files and view them without unzipping.

Comment: I already knew it, and the log shows errors about deployment, pre-request, eb-engine and so on, not application error of running

Comment: @MaSao93 Did you look in `web.stdout.log`? If you see nothing, one solution is to setup [custom logging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.logging.html#health-logs-extend) and configure Django `LOGGING` to log to a file, for example.

Answer (score 0):

There might be multiple things you might be missing. The first two things I would do is:

1. As @sanNeck suggested, try to put Debug=True in your settings (not recommended in production) which will give you a hint of the error.
2. Check if you have installed all the packages correctly on your ElasticBeanStalk. Try to pull the error logs from the console and try to find any missing packages.